# Аналог BorderLayout на HTML

Tags: html, css

Нужно создать аналог `BorderLayout` в Swing, только для HTML. Предполагается, что добавляться могут любые элементы.

[image]

То есть `North` и `South` должны растягиваться по ширине, `West` и `East` - по высоте, а `Center` - занимать максимальную площадь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это так и называется - html layout, зайдите на [генератор шаблонов](http://csstemplater.com/), выберите резиновый шаблон, два сайдбара по сторонам(они должны быть фиксированными по ширине) и скачивайте html-заготовку.